# Is it true that (const T v) is never necessary in C?

Tags: c, constants

For example:

```
void func(const int i);
```

Here,the `const` is unnecessary since all parameters are passed by value(including pointers).

Is that true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All parameters in C are indeed passed by value, which means that the actual argument will not change regardless of whether you include that `const` or not.

However, that does not mean that `const` here is "never necessary". Whether it is necessary or unnecessary depends on what you want to achieve.

If you want to prevent any attempts to modify the parameter inside the function, then the `const` *is* necessary, of course.

There is a fairly popular (and pretty reasonable) coding guideline that says that function parameters should never be modified inside the function, i.e. that at any point of function's execution all parameters must retain their original values. Under this guideline it would actually make perfect sense to *always* include that `const` in *all* parameter declarations.

Comment: The fact whether that argument will remain unchanged anyway in C is fatal for me in this case ...

Comment: I ask this because I'm reading a book which says `const T v` alike stuff is unnecessary,should use `const T *p` instead.

Answer (score 1):

const is just used by the precompiler, to notice about errors...

Note that this is perfectly valid:

```
void foo( const char * bar )
{
    char * baz = ( char * )bar;

    baz++;
}
```

So it's never necessary, but it just makes the code more readable, and informs you the pointer should never change...

Comment: `const` in `const char * bar` is useful,but `const` in `const char bar` is never useful in C,true?

Comment: Depends if you want a warning or not when trying to change the value from your function, even if it won't affect the value from the outside...